# Match UISegmentedControl's color with that of translucent navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uisegmentedcontrol

I am adding a segmented control directly under the (translucent) navigation bar, and want it to have the same color. I am trying to make it look like it's part of the navigation bar.

```
isOpaque = false
layer.opacity = 0.85
let bkImg = UIImage(color: .systemBackground.withAplhaComponent(0.85), size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 16))
segmentedCtrl.setBackgroundImage(bkImg, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
setDividerImage(bkImg, forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
```

I've tried playing with the opacity of the segmented control, and the color of `bkImg`, but that  has no effect at all. It would have been quicker to just write a custom tab bar from scratch - the segmented control in iOS 13 is impossible to customize.

Comment: I remember struggling to find a good solution for a recent project and I ended up using the [BetterSegmentedControl Framework](https://github.com/gmarm/BetterSegmentedControl) instead, which allows lots of customization, give it a try if a Framework is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a total hack, but it looks good.

[image]

```
class CustomSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    private var underline: UIView!

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        underline = UIView()
        underline.backgroundColor = tintColor
        view.addSubvie(underline)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Set background color to match navigation bar
        let bgColor = UIColor.systemBackground.hsbComponents.brightness == 1.0
            ? UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.028) // light
            : UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.073) // dark
        let img = UIImage(color: bgColor, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 16))
        setBackgroundImage(img, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        setDividerImage(img, forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)

        // Bonus: underline below selected tab
        var frame = underline.frame
        let tabWidth = self.frame.width / CGFloat(numberOfSegments)
        frame.origin.x = CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex) * tabWidth
        frame.origin.y = self.frame.height - 2.0
        frame.size.width = tabWidth
        underline.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This effect can be accomplished by putting the `UISegmentedControl` inside of a `UIToolbar`, and positioning that `UIToolbar` beneath the `UINavigationBar`. Once inside of a `UIToolbar`, the `UISegmentedControl` takes on the same appearance that it has in a `UINavigationBar`.

If you want the `UIToolBar` to blend into the `UINavigationBar`, you will need to apply all of the same appearance options to the `UIToolBar` that you do to the `UINavigationBar` (e.g. `barTintColor` and `tintColor`).

I do not know how to tweak the `UISegmentedControl` itself to mimic the appearance that the navigation bar and toolbar apply, but with this strategy we do not need to.